# SATA ports not working, do I need to update my motherboard BIOS?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata, pata

SATA HDD not detected during POST, Is there a converter cable for IDE harddrive to be connected in a SATA port on a motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

SATA to IDE converters (not mere cables) do exist and are about US $10.

However discovering why the SATA HDD is not detected might be the best solution.

- Are all cables (incl. power) connected?
- Does it work in another computer?

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

There is, but at first you should check whether you have the *On-board SATA controller* enabled in the BIOS settings. If it is and the hard drive is still undetected, you should do a method called *contratesting*. It involves

- using your harddrive in another person's (ask your friend) computer
- using someone elses harddrive in your computer

It will determine whether it is your hard drive being faulty or the motherboard itself.

SATA->IDE adapter cables does exist, you can search them on Amazon or eBay, but be careful as with using such cable you will lose the capabilities of SATA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older motherboard that supports say SATA II and you are trying to add a hard drive that is SATA III, it may not work.  Some hard drives won't run at the older level.  But, some hard drives also have jumper settings to change it to run at the older level.  I don't know if this is your problem, but it wouldn't hurt to check.

I actually had this problem with a West Digital SATA II drive.  I was trying to upgrade my storage on a older server I had and it would not recognize at all.  Once I jumpered the hard drive it was noticed.

I would not convert a SATA drive to IDE.  That is working backwards and the performance may really drop.